# системный вызов write пишет какие-то нечитабельные символы в файл

Tags: linux, c, unix

вот программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Использование: %s <файл> <текст для добавления>\n", argv[0]);
         exit(EX_USAGE);
    }

    FILE* f = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    write((long int)f, &argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
    close((ssize_t)f);

    return 0; 
}
```

она пишет какие-то нечитабельные символы в файл.

как побороть?

и да, предупреждение компилятора тоже неплохо бы починить...

вот как он ругается:

```
append.c: В функции «main»:
append.c:14:12: предупреждение: при инициализации целое преобразуется в 
указатель без приведения типа [-Wint-conversion]
   FILE* f = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
             ^
```

Comment: Компилятор правильно ругается. Так как open() возвращает целое число. Вы уверены, что хотите использовать не [fopen](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)?

Comment: такая задача. как  вообще с open работать? @retorta

Comment: Кодировка консоли, куда печатается текст, не совпадает с кодировкой файла. Если в консоли что-то вроде `РџСЂРѕРІРµСЂРє`, значит, консоль работает в однобайтовой кодировке, а исходники в UTF-8. Если сплошные вопросительные знаки — значит наоборот, консоль работает в UTF-8, а файл в однобайтовой кодировке. *Ваша задача — пересохранить файл в ту же кодировку, что использует консоль.*

Comment: Написан, конечно, бред (полное непонимание ситуации). Основная же ошибка это `&argv[2]` в `write()`. Если бы вы написали просто `argv[2]`, то не взирая на все остальное, в файле с именем, переданным в первом аргументе оказался бы текст второго аргумента вызова программы.

Comment: Что же касается -- *" как вообще с open работать?"*, то совет один -- взять и внимательно прочесть `man 2 open` и `man 2 write` (и все SEE ALSO к ним)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Системный вызов **open** возвращает целое — номер файлового дескриптора — и
имеет следующий интерфейс:

> ```
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
> ```
>
> **open** возвращает новый описатель файла или -1 в случае ошибки (в этом
>   случае значение переменной *errno* устанавливается должным образом).

Так описано на странице руководства [**open**(2)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=open&category=2).

В вашем коде вы присваиваете результат этого вызова указателю на структуру *FILE*. Вероятно, вы перепутали означенную функцию с библиотечной [**fopen**(3)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fopen&category=3).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Использование: %s <файл> <текст для добавления>\n", argv[0]);
         exit(EX_USAGE);
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    write(fd, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
    close(fd);

    return 0; 
}
```

надо было типом int объявлять дескриптор...
теперь все работает и я понимаю, чем fopen отличается от open...